# Angular Typeahead directive - access the matches elements

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

How can i get the first element suggested by the Angular Typeahead to appear in the inputbox, instead of just in the dropdown? I've searched, but i cant seem to find how to access the elements shown in the dropdown. The idea is that the suggestion comes as a background text whenever the user has started typing, as you can see in the [typeahead.js example](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/)

```
<input type="text" ng-model="selected" typeahead-min-length="0" typeahead="state for state in states | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control"> <!--Here i want the first suggestion -->
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/nQYm83onnkUHa5tUFCk6?p=preview

Not even a simple {{ matches[0] }} will give the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="http://angular-ui.github.com/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.6.0.js"></script>
  <script src="example.js"></script>
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <alert type="'info'">Typeahead from <a href="http://angular-ui.github.com/bootstrap/">http://angular-ui.github.com/bootstrap/</a>"</alert>
  <div class='container-fluid' ng-controller="TypeaheadCtrl">
    <pre>Mod: {{result}}</pre>
    <pre>Res: {{citiesList.list[0]}}</pre>
    <input type="text" ng-model="result"
        typeahead="suggestion for suggestion in (citiesList.list= cities($viewValue)) | filter: { name: $viewValue }"
        typeahead-editable="false"
        typeahead-min-length="3"
        typeahead-wait-ms="500"
        typeahead-append-to-body="true"
        typeahead-on-select='citiesList.list[0] = $item'
        >
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/L5WFBzZmj1FofCxKQwiU?p=preview)

Could somebody improve this variant?

Answer (score 1):

If i understood correct , you want to show first value of states array in placeholder if yes then    Try this : `<input type="text" placeholder ="{{states[0]}}" ng-model="selected" typeahead-min-length="0" typeahead="state for state in states | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control">`

Comment: I am sorry if i was a bit unclear - you solved my problem almost perfect. Actually i want the first suggestion to be shown _after_ the user has sterted typing. It's the same functionality you'll see if you press "activate example" in the [typeahead.js](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/) example, when the user type in bower

Comment: whenever you type anything in text-field the placeholder property get removed in html because you have entered something

Comment: Yes, so i see "placeholder" is the wrong word to use - if you check out the typeahead.js example linked over you'll see what i mean. The first suggestion is appended to the input box as a "disabled" text in the background.

Comment: After some inspection i see that the suggestions is tied up as matches and that they are shown as ng-repeat match in matches, i ideally want to see matches[0] but somehow {{matches[0]}} or {{ matches[0].label }} wont work.